# Modiying the top bar in the css file

Tags: html, wordpress, css, web

I have a wordpress website and I am attempting to remove the top black bar from my website.

Using Firebug, I figured out the code is this

```
<div class="top-bar">
```

But removing this will effect others which are embedded in the this code. I am afraid to modify the css file caz it may effect the code. Can anyone suggest a best way to remove the top bar with keeping intact the other components?

The website is at 192.254.143.28

@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/*----*---- << Responsive >> --------/
    /*----*---- << Desktop >> --------/

```
/* Note: Design for a width of 768px, Gutter: 30px, Unit: 32px */
@media only screen and (min-width:1119px) and (max-width:1520px) {

    #slider { min-height:450px; }
    .property-search-container.type2 { top:20%; }
    .property-search-container.type1 {width: 581px; }
    .boxed .container, .boxed .top-bar .top-container { width:1000px; }
    .boxed .wrapper, .boxed #header-wrapper { width:1060px; }
    .boxed #slider { min-height:416px; }

    .boxed .caroufredsel_wrapper, #bbar-wrapper .dt-sc-ads-carousel li { width:1000px !important; }
    .boxed .caroufredsel_wrapper .properties.dt-sc-one-third   { width:313px !important; }
    .dt-sc-ads-carousel-wrapper ul.dt-sc-ads-carousel, #bbar-wrapper .dt-sc-ads-carousel li { height:68px !important; }
    #bbar-wrapper{ display: none; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:960px) and (max-width:1120px) {

    .container, .top-bar .top-container { width:900px; }
    .boxed .wrapper, .boxed #header-wrapper { width:940px; }
    .boxed #header .container { padding:0px 20px; }

    .dt-sc-ads-carousel-wrapper ul.dt-sc-ads-carousel, #bbar-wrapper .dt-sc-ads-carousel li { height:61px !important; }
    #bbar-wrapper{ display: none; }
    #bbar-close { top:27%; }

    /*----*****---- << Header >> ----*****----*/        
    #main-menu ul li a { padding:0px 14px; }
    #main-menu > ul > li:hover > a, #main-menu > ul > li.current_page_item > a, #main-menu > ul > li.current-menu-ancestor > a { padding:40px 14px; }

    .is-sticky #header #main-menu > ul > li:hover > a, .is-sticky #header #main-menu > ul > li.current_page_item > a, .is-sticky #header #main-menu > ul > li.current-menu-ancestor > a { padding:23px 14px; }

    .header3 #main-menu > ul > li > a, .header4 #main-menu > ul > li > a { font-size:13px; text-transform:capitalize; }

    #main-menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul { left:auto; right:200px; }

    /*----*****---- << Main >> ----*****----*/      
    #primary { width:600px; }
    #primary.content-full-width { width:100%; }

    #secondary { width:280px; }

    #slider { margin:0 0 35px; min-height:400px; }
    .property-search-container.type2 { top:20%; }

    .property-search-container.type1 {width: 581px; }

    /*----*****---- << Home >> ----*****----*/      
    .dt-sc-ico-content.type2 { width:83%; }
    .dt-sc-ico-content.type3 { width:67%; } 

    /*----*****---- << Portfolio >> ----*****----*/
    .portfolio.dt-sc-one-third { width:31.8%; }
    .dt-sc-one-third.with-sidebar { width:31%; }

    .portfolio.dt-sc-one-fourth { width:22%; }
    .portfolio.dt-sc-one-fourth.with-sidebar:hover a.zoom { left:8%; }
    .portfolio.dt-sc-one-fourth.with-sidebar:hover a.link { right:8%; }

    .portfolio.dt-sc-one-half.with-sidebar { width:48.4%; }

    .portfolio-carousel-wrapper .portfolio.dt-sc-one-third:hover a.zoom { left:27%; }
    .portfolio-carousel-wrapper .portfolio.dt-sc-one-third:hover a.link { right:27%; }

    .portfolio.dt-sc-one-column:hover a.zoom { left:42.5%; }
    .portfolio.dt-sc-one-column:hover a.link { right:42.5%; }

    .portfolio.dt-sc-one-column.with-sidebar:hover a.zoom { left:40%; }
    .portfolio.dt-sc-one-column.with-sidebar:hover a.link { right:40%; }

    .portfolio.dt-sc-one-fourth:hover a.zoom { left:23%; }
    .portfolio.dt-sc-one-fourth:hover a.link { right:23%; }

    .portfolio.dt-sc-one-half.with-sidebar:hover a.zoom { left:30%; }
    .portfolio.dt-sc-one-half.with-sidebar:hover a.link { right:30%; }

    .portfolio.dt-sc-one-third.with-sidebar:hover a.zoom { left:20%; }
    .portfolio.dt-sc-one-third.with-sidebar:hover a.link { right:20%; }

    /*----*****---- << Property >> ----*****----*/
    .page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-half .property-item:hover a.zoom, .dt-sc-one-third .property-item:hover a.zoom { left:30%; }
    .page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-half .property-item:hover a.link, .dt-sc-one-third .property-item:hover a.link { right:30%; }

    page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-third .property-item:hover a { top:34%; }
    .page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-third .property-item:hover a.zoom { left:20%; }
    .page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-third .property-item:hover a.link { right:20%; }

    .page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-fourth .property-item:hover a.zoom { left:11%; }
    .page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-fourth .property-item:hover a.link { right:11%; }

    /*----*****---- << Blog >> ----*****----*/

    .one-third.with-sidebar .blog-entry .entry-thumb-meta .entry-meta { padding:0px 5px; }
    .dt-sc-one-column.blog-thumb .entry-details { width:72%; }
    .dt-sc-one-column.with-sidebar.blog-thumb .entry-details { width:58%; }

    .dt-sc-one-half.with-sidebar .entry-meta { font-size:11px; }
    .dt-sc-one-half.with-sidebar { width:48.7% }

    .dt-sc-one-half.with-sidebar .mejs-time-rail { width:37% !important; }

    .dt-sc-one-half.with-sidebar .featured-post:before, .dt-sc-one-half.with-sidebar .sticky .featured-post:before { content:none; }
    .dt-sc-one-half.with-sidebar .featured-post { left:0px; right:auto; top:45px; }

    /*----*****---- << Team >> ----*****----*/
    .team .image { height:194px; }

    /*----*****---- << Testimonials >> ----*****----*/
    .testimonial blockquote { width:85%; }
    .testimonial-item blockquote { width:84%; }
    .dt-sc-one-half .testimonial-item blockquote { width:68%; }

    /*----*****---- << Shortcodes >> ----*****----*/
    ul.tabs-vertical-frame { width:30%; }   

    .ls-layer .button-text2 a { font-size:18px; }

    .dt-sc-one-half pre, .dt-sc-one-half code { width:95.6%; }

    .dt-sc-tabs-vertical-frame-content { width:57%; }

    /*----*****---- << Secondary >> ----*****----*/
    #secondary .widget #searchform input[type="text"] { width:196px; padding:14px 2%; }
    #secondary .widget #searchform input[type="submit"] { padding:13px; }
    .price-range label, .price-range input[type="text"] { font-size:14px; }
    .price-range .button.small { padding:10px 15px; }

    .widget.widget_calendar th, .widget.widget_calendar td { padding:10px; }

    /*----*****---- << Footer >> ----*****----*/
    #footer .widget ul li { width:86%; }
    #footer .widget.widget_calendar th, #footer .widget.widget_calendar td { padding:5px; font-size:12px; }
    #footer input[type="text"], #footer input[type="email"], #footer input[type="password"], #footer input.text, #footer textarea { width:86%; }

    #footer .widget.flickrbox .flickr-widget div { max-width:63px; }

}

/*----*****---- << Tablet (Portrait) >> ----*****----*/ 

/* Note: Design for a width of 768px, Gutter: 30px, Unit: 32px */

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:959px) {

    .container, .top-bar .top-container { width:710px; }
    .boxed .wrapper, .boxed #header-wrapper { width:750px; }
    .boxed #header .container { padding:0px 20px; }
    #bbar-wrapper{ display: none; }
    #bbar-wrapper .dt-sc-ads-carousel { width:61px; }
    #bbar-wrapper .dt-sc-ads-carousel li { width:710px !important; }

    .dt-sc-ads-carousel-wrapper ul.dt-sc-ads-carousel, #bbar-wrapper .dt-sc-ads-carousel li { height:48px !important; }

    .top-bar { font-size:13px; }
    #bbar-close { top:21%; }

    /*----*****---- << Header >> ----*****----*/        
    #logo { width:27%; }
    #logo img { max-width:100%; margin:0px; }
    #logo h2 a { font-size:20px; }

    .header3 #logo img, .header4 #logo img { margin:0px; }

    #main-menu > ul > li { padding:41px 0px; }
    #main-menu ul li a { padding:0px 11px; font-size:12px; text-transform:capitalize; }
    #main-menu > ul > li:hover > a, #main-menu > ul > li.current_page_item > a, #main-menu > ul > li.current-menu-ancestor > a { padding:40px 11px; }

    .megamenu-child-container > ul.sub-menu > li { width:200px; }

    .is-sticky #header #main-menu > ul > li { padding:24px 0px; }
    .is-sticky #header #main-menu > ul > li:hover > a, .is-sticky #header #main-menu > ul > li.current_page_item > a, .is-sticky #header #main-menu > ul > li.current-menu-ancestor > a { padding:23px 11px; }


    .header3 #main-menu > ul > li > a, .header4 #main-menu > ul > li > a, .header3 #main-menu > ul > li:hover > a, .header3 #main-menu > ul > li.current_page_item > a, .header4 #main-menu > ul > li:hover > a, .header4 #main-menu > ul > li.current_page_item > a, .is-sticky #header.header3 #main-menu > ul > li:hover > a, .is-sticky #header.header3 #main-menu > ul > li.current_page_item > a, .is-sticky #header.header4 #main-menu > ul > li:hover > a, .is-sticky #header.header4 #main-menu > ul > li.current_page_item > a, .header3 #main-menu > ul > li.current-menu-ancestor > a, .header4 #main-menu > ul > li.current-menu-ancestor > a, .is-sticky #header.header3 #main-menu > ul > li.current-menu-ancestor > a, .is-sticky #header.header4 #main-menu > ul > li.current-menu-ancestor > a { padding-left:12px; padding-right:12px; }

    #main-menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul { left:auto; right:200px; }

    .megamenu-4-columns-group .megamenu-child-container { width:920px; }
    .megamenu-2-columns-group .megamenu-child-container { width:460px; }

    /*----*****---- << Main >> ----*****----*/      
    #primary { width:500px; }
    #primary.content-full-width { width:100%; }

    #secondary { width:190px; }

    #slider { margin:0 0 35px; min-height:400px; }
    .property-search-container.type2 { top:17%; width:70%; }
    .property-search-container.type1 {width: 581px; }
    /*----*****---- << Home >> ----*****----*/  
    .dt-sc-intro-text.type1 h4 { font-size:15px; }
    .dt-sc-intro-text.type1 h6 { font-size:13px; }

    .dt-sc-ico-content.type2 { width:77.5%; }
    .dt-sc-ico-content.type3 { width:58%; } 

    .dt-sc-intro-text.type2 a, .dt-sc-intro-text.type4 a, .dt-sc-intro-text.type3 a { padding:11px 12px; font-size:12px; }  

    /*----*****---- << Breadcrumb >> ----*****----*/    
    .breadcrumb span { margin-top:3px; }
    .breadcrumb h1 { font-size:18px; }

    .main-phone-no p { font-size:18px; }
    .main-phone-no p a { font-size:14px; }

    /*----*****---- << Property >> ----*****----*/
    .dt-sc-one-half .property-item:hover a.zoom { left:33.5%; }
    .dt-sc-one-half .property-item:hover a.link { right:33.5%; }

    .page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-half .property-item:hover a.zoom { left:27%; }
    .page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-half .property-item:hover a.link { right:27%; }

    .dt-sc-one-third .property-item:hover a.zoom { left:25%; }
    .dt-sc-one-third .property-item:hover a.link { right:25%; }

    .page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-third .property-item a { top:32%; }
    .page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-third .property-item:hover a.zoom { left:15%; }
    .page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-third .property-item:hover a.link { right:15%; }

    .dt-sc-one-third .property-item .property-details .property-content { text-align:center; }
    .dt-sc-one-third .property-item .property-details .property-price, .dt-sc-one-third .property-item .property-details .dt-sc-button { float:none; }

    .dt-sc-one-fourth .property-item:hover a.zoom { left:18%; }
    .dt-sc-one-fourth .property-item:hover a.link { right:18%; }

    .page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-fourth .property-item:hover a.zoom { left:3%; }
    .page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-fourth .property-item:hover a.link { right:3%; }
    .page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-fourth .property-item .image-overlay a.zoom, .page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-fourth .property-item .image-overlay a.link { top:22%; }

    .page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-third .property-item .property-thumb-meta .property-type, .page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-third .property-item .property-contract-type, .dt-sc-one-fourth .property-item .property-thumb-meta .property-type, .dt-sc-one-fourth .property-item .property-contract-type { padding:10px; font-size:13px; text-transform:capitalize; }

    .page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-fourth .property-item .property-contract-type { top:5px; }
    .page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-fourth .property-item .property-thumb-meta .property-type { top:42px; }

    .page-with-sidebar .dt-sc-one-fourth .property-item .property-thumb { overflow:hidden; }

    .dt-sc-one-fourth .property-item .image-overlay a.zoom, .dt-sc-one-fourth .property-item .image-overlay a.link { top:31%; }
```

Comment: Website is unreachable. Post is unclear. Contains no good information. -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a quick solution please add to your css: `#bbar-wrapper { display: none; }`.

If you want to remove topbar menu also you have to add `div.top-bar { display: none; }` and change `#header` div height.

The best way to remove that is to search your template php files and see where where this div created.

Good Luck!

Comment: Please have a look at the part of CSS file. I have tried it but failed. Cant see any changes:(

Comment: Your solution works but now the header has too much height :( can i reduce it ? 192.254.143.28 (see)

Comment: Please try #header { height: 100px !important; }

Comment: Wao! Perfect! One last thing PLEASE~~ I have a constant selection on "Home" of the menu which is not removed even when i press other menu options. how can i remove it?

Comment: Your menu adds two classes "current-menu-item" and "current_page_item" to format active items. you have to check rules that using them and disable them.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know the right way to do it but you can do this

```
.top-bar{ margin-top:-70px;}
```

it will move it above for more help atleast share your code

Answer (score 1):

you can edit your style.css file in the directory /wp-content/themes/rl/style.css
Add the following css at the end of the style.css file

```
.top-bar { display: none; }
```